# Laravel Nova indexQuery scopes reuse

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I do have a policy based right management for my application in place and I am using Nova as a Backend for the application.

Now everything works inside nova and I would like to setup an additional API for my external applications.

I do have to override the `indexQuery` for most of my resources, as users get access to only a limited scope e.g. for the `Customer` resource:

```
public static function indexQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    // Admins and office users can see all customers
    if($user->authorizeRoles(['admin', 'office'])) {
        return $query;
    }

    // A user can only see customers associated with a job they work on
    $query
        ->select('customers.*')
        ->join('jobs', 'jobs.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id')
        ->join('teams', 'jobs.team_id', '=','teams.id')
        ->join('team_user', 'teams.id', '=', 'team_user.team_id')
        ->where('team_user.user_id', '=', $user->id);

    return $query;
}
```

Now for the API I basically need the same scopes and I wonder where to put this code. My first thought was to add a scope to the `Customer` model, so I would add a scope with a parameter:

```
/**
 * Limit the results to the customers the user is able to see
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
 * @param \App\User $user
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public function scopeVisibleToUser($query, $user) {
    if($user->authorizeRoles(['admin', 'office'])) {
        return $query;
    }

    // A user can only see customers associated with a job they work on
    $query
        ->select('customers.*')
        ->join('jobs', 'jobs.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id')
        ->join('teams', 'jobs.team_id', '=','teams.id')
        ->join('team_user', 'teams.id', '=', 'team_user.team_id')
        ->where('team_user.user_id', '=', $user->id);

    return $query;
}
```

Is there any way to apply the scope within the `indexQuery` method without creating a dummy Customer object?

```
use App\Customer as AppCustomer;

/**
 * Build an "index" query for the given resource.
 *
 * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest  $request
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public static function indexQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    return (new AppCustomer())->scopeVisibleToUser($query, $user);
}
```

Comment: What about using Customer::class as real time facade and make use of static method calls ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using [real-time facades](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/facades#real-time-facades), you may treat any class in your application
>   as if it were a facade.

```
use Facades\App\Customer as AppCustomer;

/**
 * Build an "index" query for the given resource.
 *
 * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest  $request
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public static function indexQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    return AppCustomer::visibleToUser($query, $user);
}
```

Comment: yeah, well the "real" trick is to use a static function, will do so now, so accepted as an answer, if I need a model instance function I can still call the Class

Comment: Under the hood "When the real-time facade is used, your AppCustomer class implementation will be resolved out of the service container using the portion of the  class name that appears after the Facades prefix."